# Packaging a Play! application straight into a WAR

Tags: java, playframework, war

I am using Play's `war` command to package up my application into a WAR file for deployment, like so:

`play war mydir -o myapp --zip`

([Discovering `--zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630820/cant-export-play-app-as-war) has sure saved me a lot of time!)  This command creates a WAR file `myapp.war` just like it's supposed to, and also an exploded version of the WAR in a directory `myapp/`.

I've changed the names of my directories to avoid confusion, but often I want the WAR file to have the same name as my app directory (`mydir`, in this example).  `play war mydir -o mydir --zip` fails, of course, rather than overwrite my app directory, which is good.

In a case like this I'd like Play! to skip the directory bit and just get my app straight into a WAR file.  Actually, name conflict or not, I'd like to do that anyway; my server is not the same as my dev box, so I just move the WAR file and don't do anything with the exploded version.

So, is there some way to get Play to skip making the exploded version?  I've consulted `play help war` to no avail.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible (at least for the moment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I feel kinda lazy for having asked this.  Clearly I can just do it myself:

```
play war mydir -o myapp --zip
rm -rf myapp
mv myapp.war mydir.war
```

or for Windows

```
play war mydir -o myapp --zip
rmdir /S myapp
move myapp.war mydir.war
```

and drop those commands in a `.sh`/`.bat` file.  Hope that helps someone in the future.